# F# crashes on Mono 2.10

Tags: f#, mono

After reading some reports about the inadequacies of the Mono 2.6 garbage collector, I decided to give Mono 2.10 a go. I found that the 2.10 runtime crashes with the following simple F# program:

```
let rec f x acc =
  if x = 0 then acc
  else f (x - 1) (acc + 1)

f 10 0
```

Equivalent looping C# code runs just fine as does an F# hello world program. The F# code also works ok with Mono 2.6 and .Net. Can anyone else reproduce this? Is it a bug or is it just my installation?

Here are the various runtimes I've tried and results I got.

- Mono 2.10.2 (compiled from sources on Debian Squeeze)

  ```
  -- "Stack overflow: IP: 0x4153bb84, fault addr: (nil)"
  ```
- Mono 2.8 (compiled from sources on Debian Squeeze)

  ```
  -- "Native stacktrace: ..."
  ```
- Mono 2.10.2 (Windows binary)

  ```
  -- "mono.exe has stopped working" dialog.
  ```
- Mono 2.10.2 (VMware image)

  ```
  -- Segmentation fault
  ```
- Mono 2.6.7 (bundled with Debian Squeeze)

  ```
  -- Works fine
  ```

The F# compiler used was from the November 2010 CTP.

Comment: Granted the numbers of platforms/configurations you've tried, this is obviously a bug in Mono. Please open a bug and attach the executable. Thanks.

Comment: This is probably due to Mono's lack of tail call optimization. See here http://flyingfrogblog.blogspot.com/2009/01/mono-does-not-support-tail-calls.html.

Comment: @sashang: I was in the process of testing Mono's tail call handling when I came across this. I doubt this is the cause here though because a) it crashes on small inputs and b) the generated code doesn't contain any tail calls, only imperative loops.

Comment: @Jb Evain: I've now submitted a bug report.

Comment: @petebu: bug number/url?

Comment: @IanNorton. #693905. https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=693905

Comment: @petebu: Could you post a link to the bug report as a self-answer and accept it?

Comment: I've just compiled mono today from the sources, version 2.10.2, and executed @petebu program and everything executed perfectly. I'm using Ubuntu 11.04. If I can be of any help please "shout" ;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've reported this problem as bug #693905 at https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=693905.